# Issue with RTK Query Reauthentication in Next.js SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, refresh-token, rtk-query

I'm encountering a problem with RTK Query's ReauthBaseQuery in a Next.js SSR (Server-Side Rendering) setup. I have a custom API slice (BaseQueryReAuth) that includes logic for refreshing tokens when a 403 status error is encountered. The issue is that the cookies are not being sent back to the server in the refresh route.

**API Slice (ApiSlice.ts):**

```js
import { BaseQueryFn, createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { ReadonlyRequestCookies } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies';

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  credentials: 'include',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { extra }) => {
    const cookies = (extra as any)?.cookies as ReadonlyRequestCookies;
    const accessToken = cookies.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME)?.value;
    console.log(' ~ file: ApiSlice.ts:10 ~ accessToken:', accessToken);
    if (accessToken) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
    }
    return headers;
  },
});

// wrapper for BaseQuery
const BaseQueryReAuth: BaseQueryFn = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
  if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    console.log('sending refresh token');
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('auth/refresh', api, extraOptions);
    result = refreshResult;
  }
  return result;
};

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: BaseQueryReAuth,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

**Server-Side Component (layout.tsx):**

```js
import OutInAnimation from '@/animation/OutInAnimation';
import AuthPageTop from '@/components/AuthPage/AuthPageTop';
import { userApi } from '@/global/apis/UserApi';
import { makeStore } from '@/global/store';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';

const UserPageLayout: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = async ({ children }) => {
  const { data } = await makeStore(cookies()).dispatch(userApi.endpoints.getProfile.initiate());
  console.log(' ~ file: layout.tsx:11 ~ constUserPageLayout:FC<{children:ReactNode}>= ~ data:', data);

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full h-screen bg-whatsapp-light-bg dark:bg-whatsapp-dark-bg flex place-items-center justify-center">
      <AuthPageTop noLogo className="dark:bg-whatsapp-dark-bg absolute top-0" />
      <OutInAnimation className="absolute container h-[96%] bg-white">{children}</OutInAnimation>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPageLayout;
```

**Store Configuration (store.ts):**

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from './apis/ApiSlice';
import { sideBarOverlaySlice } from './features/SideBarOverlaySlice';
import { modalSlice } from './features/ModalSlice';
import { ChatSlice } from './features/ChatSlice';
import { ReadonlyRequestCookies } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies';

export const makeStore = (cookies: ReadonlyRequestCookies | undefined) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
      sideBarOverlaySlice: sideBarOverlaySlice.reducer,
      modalSlice: modalSlice.reducer,
      ChatSlice: ChatSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware(getDefaultMiddleware) {
      return getDefaultMiddleware({
        thunk: {
          extraArgument: {
            cookies,
          },
        },
      }).concat(apiSlice.middleware);
    },
  });
};

// Infer the type of makeStore
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootStateMakeStore = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>;
export type AppDispatchMakeStore = AppStore['dispatch'];
```

**Store Provider (StoreProvider.tsx):**

```js
'use client';
import { AppStore, makeStore } from '@/global/store';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const StoreProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore(undefined);
  }
  return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default StoreProvider;
```

When making a request to fetch user data using **userApi.endpoints.getProfile.initiate()**, the **accessToken** is successfully logged. However, the received data is undefined. It appears that the **cookies**, especially the **refreshToken**, are not being sent back to the server during the SSR process.

I've attempted to include the refresh token in the header, but I encountered an issue when the server sets httpsOnly cookies. It seems that the cookies are not being set.

Any guidance on how to address this discrepancy and ensure that cookies, especially the refresh token, are sent and received correctly during token refresh in SSR would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your valuable insights!